# Can I manipulate SalesForce data using VisualForce

Tags: data, import, lightning-connect

To preface: I'm unfamiliar with VisualForce and the Apex language (prior to a little research yesterday).

The problem: I'd like to retrieve data from a SalesForce entry (in this case an Account), use that data to retrieve additional data from an external site (which I am fairly certain I know how to do using Javascript), then insert that external data back into the SalesForce entry in a different field.

The basic thing I'd like to know is if this is possible. I'm not looking for the specific code, just whether or not what I want to do is possible before I spend too much time researching the language.

Alternately, if I'm looking at the wrong thing and there's a more appropriate way to do this within SalesForce, that would also be appreciated.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible with Apex and/or VisualForce (I think you'll need VF to select account). You'll also need to get the data from external site. Check the possibilities of integration i.e. via REST/SOAP.

Comment: Thank you! And I will check out REST/SOAP as well. Thanks again!